# duplicate each space in a given string

Tags: string, in-place

I found the following question in many interviews (not my interview).

given a string, you need to replace each space with 2 spaces.
you may assume that your string has enough place for adding the required spaces.
you need to do it in place, memory allocation is not allowed.

I don't understand how to implement this without override letters.

Comment: Is this for a particular programming language or a general algorithm question? Anyway, it says the string has enough memory allocated to it in order to contain the extra spaces.  If you don't want to "override letters" you'll need to shift letters over. Doing the shift correctly is the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a lot of context in your question. Let's assume it's a programming interview and you are dealing with a low level language like C or assembler. Let's also assume that the string has a count and/or ends in a null, like 'this is a string\0\0\0\0'

I would scan the string from beginning to end and count the spaces, let's call that C. Then I would work backward through the string on character at a time moving each character forward by C positions. Each time a space is encountered, copy the space forward by C positions, subtract one from C, and then move the space by C positions. Stop when C is 0.

Here, nulls/unused are represented by a period.

```
this is a string....  C=3
this is a string..g.
this is a string.ng.
this is a stringing.
this is a strinring.
this is a stritring.
this is a strstring.
this is a st string.
this is a s  string. C=2
this is a a  string.
this is   a  string.
this iss  a  string.  C=1
this iis  a  string.  
this  is  a  string.  C=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Shifting the string following a found space is required by one letter. To reduce time needed to reduce the shifting part, I would use this approach:

1. Count the number of space. I will call this count `c`.
2. Shift the string to the number of spaces to the right (I'm assuming here a left to right reading direction.)
3. Start a loop starting at offset `c` until the end of the string:

   1. Initialize a counter for the already duplicated space, called `s`, with 0
   2. Copy the letter at current position to current position - `c` + `s`
   3. If the letter was a space, increment `s` and add a space to position - `c` + 1

Not sure if all the offset are correctly calculated in my mind, correct it if needed. But because this is just an interview question to idea is just to sketch a correct algorithm.